# Zend PDF - save permissions

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf, zend-pdf

I'm trying to save a simple pdf with one page but it doesn't work. This is what I do:

```
try {
       // create PDF
       $pdf = new Zend_Pdf();

       // create A4 page
       $page = new Zend_Pdf_Page(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);

       // define font resource
       $font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA);

       // set font for page
       // write text to page
       $page->setFont($font, 24)
           ->drawText('That which we call a rose,', 72, 720)
           ->drawText('By any other name would smell as sweet.', 72, 620);

       // add page to document
       $pdf->pages[] = $page;

       // save as file
       $pdf->save("/test.pdf");
       echo 'SUCCESS: Document saved!';
   } catch (Zend_Pdf_Exception $e) {
       die ('PDF error: ' . $e->getMessage());
   } catch (Exception $e) {
       die ('Application error: ' . $e->getMessage());
   }
```

I always get this error:

> PDF error: Can not open '/test.pdf' file for writing.

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775768/zend-pdf-permission-problem) stackoverflow topic but I didn't help me much. They say to change the save path, but change it to what? Let's say for example I want to download it to my Downloads folder, how can I do this?

My Downloads folder on mac is : `/Users/myname/Downloads`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try for save in Zend app directory

```
  $pdf->save("test.pdf");
```

or for save in Downloads

```
   $pdf->save("/Users/myname/Downloads/test.pdf");
```

Comment: So web server user may not have permissions for writing in that directories. You can try to save in /tmp/test.pdf if that works change permissions to proper one for directory where you want save it.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have write permissions on the folder with ls -ld. If you do not have write permission in the folder use chmod to give it to yourself.

Comment: That I have permissions on my Downloads folder? Do I have to set the option true local or .. ?

Comment: I don't know what your exact set up is like, but if the folder does not have proper write permissions it will not allow php to write files. Use ls -ld to find out - it will give you a sense of what the folder is allowed to do.

Comment: A question, when I save it, will it save it to my server or to the user his pc?

Comment: Do you maybe have a tutorial how I can save the file to the users Downloads folder? I don't need the file on my server.

Comment: Once you've created the file on your server, redirect the user to the file and it will give them the download panel, then once you are sure that the user has downloaded the file you may delete it, or leave on the server to be deleted by a chron job or othersuch process.